# What is the largest optimal repo size that Git can support?

Tags: git, svn

1- Can git support a repo size ie repo size (unit:TB) > 1TB and < 2 TB ?

2- What's the upper limit of git repo size before its performance degrades ?

3- Is SVN's maintenance performance better than Git's in TB repo size range ?

Thank you

Comment: Potentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57134772/what-operations-become-slow-when-git-repos-become-large-and-why

Comment: hi torek thanks for responding. > 1TB and < 2 TB repo size. Redid question

Answer (score 1):

Git can deal with arbitrarily sized repositories.  However, 1 TB is generally larger than recommended.  The largest repositories that tend to be in practical use are typically 300 GB or so, and those typically will use sparse checkout and partial clone to improve performance to an acceptable level.

However, usually the reason that repositories are very large is because users are storing binary build artifacts or binary dependencies in them or because the repository is a monorepo.  You should not store binary build artifacts or binary dependencies in repositories at all; these should be stored in an artifact server and, if they're dependencies, referenced (e.g., by SHA-256 hash or URL).  Also, using multiple repositories instead of a monorepo results in better performance because the repositories are smaller.

If you need to store a repository with a large number of binary assets (e.g., images or tarballs), you may wish to use Git LFS, which can store most of these outside of the repository, which is another way to make the repository smaller.

So, in general, Git won't perform at its optimum if you have a repository of this size, but in the vast majority of cases, your repository can generally be made much, much smaller if you structure it properly, in which case Git will perform acceptably or better.